# Which fallacy is it to think because someone committed a fallacy in one argument, they'd commit a fallacy in a different argument?

Tags: fallacies, argumentation

**What's the name of the fallacy?**

If I assume, someone X has done a fallacy in other argument `A1` so he will do a fallacy in another argument `A2`. What would be the name of this fallacy I am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**

[Hasty generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulty_generalization#Hasty_generalization).

**Long Answer**

When a thinker has specific experience or experiences, and then draws a general conclusion about them without adequate warrant, this is a hasty or faulty generalization. From WP:

> X is true for A.
> X is true for B.
> Therefore, X is true for C, D, E, etc.

With your concrete example and the implicit proposition:

> X has committed fallacy F1 in Argument 1
> (A person who commits a fallacy will likely or inevitably do so again.)
> Therefore, X has committed fallacy F1 in Argument 2.

Obviously, if Argument 2 doesn't actually contain the fallacy, the conclusion is false. It is a dull intellect indeed that uses induction on a single instance of experience, or if you prefer a single-data point to derive a general rule! It might be more tenable on the 20th invocation of the fallacy in an argument that one can have some comfort in such a conclusion. Of course, people can change, and hence the [scandal of induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_induction).

Answer (score 1):

[Non-sequitur](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/logicalfallacies/Non-Sequitur).

The conclusion does not follow from the premise.

I can be wrong about many things, yet be correct about something else.